# OpenCV error using inverse

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I'm working SIFT implementation using Visual C++. My code throws an error while taking inverse:

```
/// Load the source image    
src = imread("C:/Users/Adithyaanirudhha/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/ConsoleApplication2/pa.jpg", 1);

if (display_caption("Original Image") != 0) { return 0; }

dst = src.clone();
width = src.size().width;
height = src.size().height;
Size size(height,width);
if (display_dst(DELAY_CAPTION) != 0) { return 0; }
cvtColor(src, src, CV_RGB2GRAY);
/// Applying Gaussian blur


//for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
//{
//resize(src, src, size / 2);
k = 2 ^ (1 / 2);
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
//if (display_caption("Gaussian Blur") != 0) { return 0; }
GaussianBlur(src, dst, Size(), 1.6*k, 1.6*k);
if (display_dst(DELAY_BLUR*10) != 0) { return 0; }
k = k * k;
dst.copyTo(dest[m]);
//dest[m] = dst;
m++;
}
//}

width2 = dog[1].size().width;
height2 = dog[1].size().height;
Size sizes(width2,height2);
Mat dog_inv(sizes,0,CV_64F);
for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
{
    if(m1!=3 || m1 != 6 || m1 != 9)
    subtract(dest[m1 + 1], dest[m1], dog[n],noArray(),-1);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Sobel(dog[i], grad_x, CV_16S, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    convertScaleAbs(grad_x, grad_x);
    transpose(grad_x, temp);
    Sobel(dog[i], grad_x_2, CV_16S, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    convertScaleAbs(grad_x_2, grad_x_2);
    c = invert(dog[i],dog_inv, DECOMP_LU);

    Sobel(dog[i], grad_x_2_1, CV_16S, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    convertScaleAbs(grad_x_2_1, grad_x_2_1);
    //imshow(window_name,src);
    //grad_x_2_1 = grad_x_2_1.inv(CV_32F);
    multiply(grad_x_2_1, grad_x, x_max, 1, 1);
    multiply(temp, x_max, p1, 1, 1);
    transpose(x_max,temp);
    //multiply(temp, grad_x_2, p2, 1, 1);
    multiply(p2, x_max, p2, 1, 1);
    imshow(window_name, dog[1]);
    /*for (int y = 0; y < dog[i].rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < dog[i].cols; x++)
        {
            dog[i].at<Vec3b>(y, x) = (-1 * (p1.at<Vec3b>(y, x)) + 0.5*(p2.at<Vec3b>(y, x)) + dog[i].at<Vec3b>(y, x));
        }
    }*/
    //imshow(window_name, dog[1]);
    //imshow(window_name, src);
```

and the error is:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == CV_32F || type == CV_64F) in cv::invert,
>    file C:\buildslave64\win64_amdocl\master_PackSlave-win64-vc14-shared\opencv\mod
>   ules\core\src\lapack.cpp, line 798
>   Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == CV_32F || type == CV_64F) in cv::invert

means that you need to pass to `invert` a matrix of type `CV_32F` (float) or `CV_64F` (double). But you're passing a `CV_16S` (short), because you set this when calling:

```
Sobel(dog[i], grad_x, CV_16S, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
                      ^^^^^^
```

So you can

1. change the type of the matrix returned by `Sobel` to `CV_32F`

   ```
    Sobel(dog[i], grad_x, CV_32F, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    c = invert(dog[i],dog_inv, DECOMP_LU);
   ```
2. or convert the matrix you pass to `invert` to the correct type

   ```
    Sobel(dog[i], grad_x, CV_16S, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    Mat tmp;
    dog[i].convertTo(tmp, CV_32F);
    c = invert(tmp,dog_inv, DECOMP_LU);
   ```

Comment: Thank you first of all and                                                                                                                   i tried the second format and  ended with error saying:    
***** VIDEOINPUT LIBRARY - 0.1995 - TFW07 *****

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (m == n) in cv::invert, file C:\buildslave64\win6
4_amdocl\master_PackSlave-win64-vc14-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\lapack.cpp,
line 822
Press any key to continue . . .                                                                              does it mean that it's not a square matix .

Comment: Try using `DECOMP_SVD` instead of `DECOMP_LU`

Comment: it worked i guess but once again it raised a different error this time :         
***** VIDEOINPUT LIBRARY - 0.1995 - TFW07 *****

OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'a
rray op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels)
, nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in cv::arithm_op, file C:\builds
lave64\win64_amdocl\master_PackSlave-win64-vc14-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\a
rithm.cpp, line 639
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't debug all your code. Check the line that is causing the error, and probably you find out that the images don't have the same size and number of channels...